# JavaScript toggle window, showing and hiding div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to achieve the toggle window for refining search results, for showing n hiding div content, but without jQuery. Anyone having links or ideas?

Comment: Have you tried programming a solution?  Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 1):

The nokia site you provided did this effect using flash but i think you want to make the same effect but using javascript and i don't know why you don't want to use jquery, it is verp powerfull and i will do the same effect.

Comment: I agree here. I normally avoid jquery like the plague as it is bulky and overused in a lot of situations, but when it comes to stuff like this you are going to be writing massive functions otherwise. Sometimes reinventing the wheel is just too much work

Comment: coz jquery is hectic, do ya have anything simple

Comment: HECTIC?! THIS IS JQUERY! *kicks zack*

Comment: Really, jQuery is just what you need for this case if you want to avoid hectic.

Comment: jQuery looks hectic at first but its very simple. It has a massive amount of functions built specifically for what you are trying to do. Reading through the 11 pages at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp will take you less time than recreating everything